# Trying to submit a form with live(), delegate and bind()

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, bind, live

Incase a form is not valid, I want to print a message in the browser console.

Folling code with **bind** works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').bind('submit', function () {
        if ($j(this).valid() == false) {
            console.log("Warning: form not valid");
        };
    });
});
```

and works as well when I replace bind by **submit**:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
```

But doesnt work when I use **delegate**:

```
$('body').delegate('form', 'submit', function () {
```

And even with **live** no success:

```
$('form').live('submit', function () {
```

Form is not dynamicly insertet. What could be the reason for that live and delegate don't work??

**EDIT**

I just found out that jquery.validate.min.js was causing the problem. Hm, but how can I prevent my own form events to be prevented?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  Why are you doing a .live on the body and not the form?

Comment: If the form is not dynamically inserted why not bind the event directly on the form element?

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy and paste, I updated the live-Part. I am using jquery 1.6.4

Comment: Because the message should also appear when I insert a form later on.

Comment: Delete the events you attach with `.submit` keep only `delegate` and see if it will work.

Comment: I tried them one after another, not at the same time.

Comment: How do you know it's doesn't fire? did you put there an alert? show the **FULL CODE + HTML**

Comment: Because the form is not valid, so the message should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have another handler either on the `form` element or an ancestor between the `form` and the `body` which is preventing the propagation of the event, either by;

1. Calling [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the event object
2. Calling [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) on the event object
3. `return false`'ing from the event handler.

You need to find that handler, and stop it doing so. Bear in mind this may be the work of a plugin you have enabled as well.

Comment: I just found out that jquery.validate.min.js was causing the problem. Hm, but how can I prevent my own form events to be prevented?

Comment: @Simon. use the `unbind` to remove their even.

Comment: @Simon: Your events and those bound by jquery.validate are processed the same. The only way to bypass those bound by jquery.validate is to unbind those events as gdoron said.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that you `return false` from a callback thus prevent this callback to fire.

See this [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/wRsm8/)

Comment: This is not the case, there are no other event bindings before.

Comment: @Simon. did you remove the events you attached with `on` and `.submit`?